# Better approach for nested query

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I am very new in Laravel.

I have this query

```
$city = City::where('slug', $slug)->first();
$city->users = $city->users()->where('gender', 'male')->get();
```

So I am wondering what is a better approach for this situation. To sum up, I need to find a city and all users belonging to the city where gender = male.

I've tried to do this but didn't work

```
$city = City::whereHas('users', function($q) {
            $q->where('gender', '=', 'male');
        })->where('slug', $slug)
          ->first();
```

What I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive this is possible with Laravel's [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).
With the relationships properly set up in your City model class you could just do

```
$city = City::where('slug', $slug)
        ->with(['users' => function ($query) {
                               $query->where('gender', 'male');
                           }])->first();
```

Comment: It worked. However, I need to catch the result using something like
$city[0]->users. Is that right? Thank you

Comment: Great! I edited the answer to get only the first result, I think that should return an object and not an array. vote answered? :)

Comment: Cool! But first isn't to get only the first row of the result? Still working that way! tks again!

Comment: Yes, thats right, now first() relates to the City. The only parameters we pass to the users query are the where clause. So then we get the first city with all the male users.

Comment: Oh! That makes sense! Mate, thank you so much! Much appreciated. 